# How to pause building with xcode?

Tags: xcode, unreal-engine4

I have to compile the UnrealEngine source code which is a huge project and takes a while to build (at least for the first time).

I came up to 160 out of 905 steps in 30 minutes, I presume more or less 2 and a half hours for the whole process.

Is there a way to pause the building process with xcode, or with any IDE / compiler ?
I'm on OS X MacBook Pro Retina. i5 processor and the standard Intel Iris GPU.

Comment: As far as i know it's not possible. But Xcode should not build frameworks when compiling your code since they are already compiled. If the engine is not compiled you should probably add a second target in your project. Then you won't have to build both targets every time. Note: This is just a general answer, I have never used that engine.

Comment: Don't know specifically about Xcode but Unreal is split up into lots of (relatively) small modules that compile to separate binaries. Therefore, if you abandon the build it should (more or less) pick up where it left off as it won't need to rebuild the existing binaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pause as such, you have to cancel the build, however any object files built are not removed, so the next time you start a build it will pick-up where it finished.

Comment: @EwanMellor Indeed; however I never remember that and always use the menu :)

Comment: Thank you I was not sure about the canceling. I confirm the .o files are not removed.